# Datepicker after localization not working when fetching from database

Tags: c#, database, xamarin.forms, localization

I am  using xamarin forms and working on localizing my app to support a different langauge(Arabic). It works and everything is localized. However, if I want to fetch information when the user enters the date of choice and clicks the search button, the datepicker value is saved with an arabic character and the database does not accept this format. 
The default date is shown like this:

```
4/22/2020 5:47:03 AM
```

After localizing it to support Arabic, it shows like this:

```
22/04/2020 05:48:33 ص
```

How do I replace the character or fix the format so that the database accepts the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I replace the character or fix the format so that the database accepts the format?

When you get DatePicker data, you can change date format using following code:

```
datepicker1.Date.ToString("M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thank you! in my case because I'm using MVVM, so I edited the value in the view model as: datefrom.ToString("M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");